# Is there a Python/Django GEDCOM Parser that would parse gedcom for django app?

Tags: gedcom, software-recommendations, data-storage

I am wondering what type of database would be best for this even.  I want to create an app for uploading a gedcom file, having it parsed and saved in a database/triple store.  Then the Django application would display the data, I think as part of a large combined genealogy of all persons that ever lived.  It seems that Semantic Web Technologies have a method for uniquely identifying such a large number of people.  One would use a URI based on a URL that one owns and controls.  One still needs a system for organizing every possible person.

I'd love to collaborate with someone on building an application of this sort.  Python is well suited for data science of this subject matter.  Translating all of this into an application that can be used by non-technical end users, that is definitely going to be a challenge.  I wonder if Big Data and Data Science could be applied to finding Genealogical information in a Giant Global Database of the type described by Tim Berner's-Lee who created the World Wide Web.

Comment: In case you have not seen it this Q&A should help with the reading GEDCOM part: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/parsing-a-gedcom

Answer (score 3):

When I read Python and Django, the obvious answer is Gramps. Please check our site at https://gramps-project.org/ to see if it would be useful for you.