# Writing GEDCOM Parser for Java 2024

Tags: software-recommendations, genealogy-community

My goal is to have my GedcomService class read a GEDCOM (.ged) file (family tree data used for genealogy) and parse it, and deposit the data into a mysql database for me to then mess with.

The problem with the options I'm finding is that links to documentation are dead. Any recommendations or advice here would be great. Equally would love pointing in the right direction.

[gedcom4j](https://github.com/frizbog/gedcom4j) looked promising, but the link to the documentation redirects multiple times until settling on a completely irrelevant site.

[gedcom5-java](https://github.com/FamilySearch/gedcom5-java) looks to have everything I could need, but there's no dependency I can find to put in my pom, and then I can't find the docs either.

[Java Parser from Dillan Quass](https://github.com/DallanQ/Gedcom) is also dead.

[Parsing a GEDCOM](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/parsing-a-gedcom) was a link I had a nose at, amongst others. I've had a look around google, stackexchange, and youtube.
Also tried:
https://www.tamurajones.net/OpenSourceGEDCOMParsers.xhtml

[Parsing a GEDCOM](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/parsing-a-gedcom)

For context, I am very new to coding (on an apprenticeship), and genealogy is a hobby of mine. This is both a passion and learning project for me. Maybe I'm missing something in the links I provided?

I'm using JDK 17 I believe, as well as maven and springboot.

Comment: If all you want is to parse a Gedcom and store the data in a relational database, then why does it matter whether it's in Java or Python or some other language?

Comment: I use php to parse a gedcom and save it to a mySQL database. It is relatively easy to do and I developed it from scratch. You may be better off doing it yourself and using it as a learning experience rather than relying on someones code. Break it down into manageable chunks so start by just extracting the names of everyone and build from there adding a gedcom tag one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer may have been closer than you realise.... the repo [*Github: FamilySearch / GEDCOM*](https://github.com/FamilySearch/GEDCOM) has a handy link right at the top of the readme that takes you to [the specs](https://gedcom.io/specs/) for many versions of the file.

Additionally, using a link from [this previous answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3617/15278) will take you to a [Github search](https://github.com/search?q=gedcom&type=Repositories&s=stars) for GEDCOM related projects that produces a list that has some projects with contributions in the last few days - IOW they're still active. [Some of them](https://github.com/Serg-Norseman/GEDKeeper/tree/master/projects/GKCore/GDModel) will have model definitions that you can translate directly from C# to Java.